# video file .mov coded with Codec: Apple ProRes (apch) is not getting played through video tag in chrome or IE11

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html5-video

I am able to play .mov files coded with H.264 in video tag. Now this .mov video which has Apple ProRes(apch) codec,(I checked codec through VLC player), is not playing in .

I tried to find out supported and unsupported video codecs,gone through [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats) link and many other links, but could not got a concrete answer.

I have also tried to play this file using quicktime plugin for safari on mac as well as windows, but failed.

Is this codec not supported in html5 video? If no, how Can I play this video in browser without using VLC plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only codec supported for IE is h.264 with mp4, you can bypass the container(mov) if the video is encoded in h.264. Since your video is encoded in diffrent format it won't be supported by html5 browsers.

In short Html5 supports h.264 or/and vp8 codec. You have reencode the videos in this format.

NOTE: Ie can play vp8(webm) videos if 3rd party plugins are installed.

So in your case either reencode or develop a plugin and ask every one to install it, easier would be reencode.